# Slowness to Remove 3,7 and 9 column from | separated txt file using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, performance

I have Pipe separated data file with huge data and i want to remove 3,7, and 9 column.
below script is working 100% fine. but its too slow its taking 5 mins for 22MB file.

> Adeel|01|test|1234589|date|amount|00|123345678890|test|all|01|
> Adeel|00|test|1234589|date|amount|00|123345678890|test|all|00|
> Adeel|00|test|1234589|date|amount|00|123345678890|test|all|00|
> Adeel|00|test|1234589|date|amount|00|123345678890|test|all|00|
> Adeel|05|test|1234589|date|amount|00|123345678890|test|all|05|
> Adeel|00|test|1234589|date|amount|00|123345678890|test|all|00|
> Adeel|00|test|1234589|date|amount|00|123345678890|test|all|00|
> Adeel|00|test|1234589|date|amount|00|123345678890|test|all|00|
> Adeel|09|test|1234589|date|amount|00|123345678890|test|all|09|
> Adeel|00|test|1234589|date|amount|00|123345678890|test|all|00|
> Adeel|00|test|1234589|date|amount|00|123345678890|test|all|00|
> Adeel|12|test|1234589|date|amount|00|123345678890|test|all|12|

```
    param
(
    # Input data file
    [string]$Path = 'O:\Temp\test.txt',
    # Columns to be removed, any order, dupes are allowed
    [int[]]$Remove = (3,6)
)

# sort indexes descending and remove dupes
$Remove = $Remove | Sort-Object -Unique -Descending

# read input lines
Get-Content $Path | .{process{
    # split and add to ArrayList which allows to remove items
    $list = [Collections.ArrayList]($_ -split '\|')

    # remove data at the indexes (from tail to head due to descending order)
    foreach($i in $Remove) {
        $list.RemoveAt($i)
    }

    # join and output
    #$list -join '|'
    $contentUpdate=$list -join '|'
    Add-Content "O:\Temp\testoutput.txt" $contentUpdate
}
}
```

Comment: Please add some sample input data (e.g. 5 rows) [to the question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72583862/edit).

Comment: Apart from `Get-Content` being slow, as mentioned in zett42's answer, note that calling `Add-Content` _in every iteration_ is slow, because the file has to be opened and closed every time. Instead, add another pipeline segment with a single `Set-Content` call. However, zett42's solution will perform best.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Get-Content` is comparatively slow. Use of the pipeline adds additional overhead.

When performance matters, [`StreamReader`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamreader?view=net-6.0) and [`StreamWriter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamwriter?view=net-6.0) can be a better choice:

```sh
param (
    # Input data file
    [string] $InputPath = 'input.txt',
    # Output data file
    [string] $OutputPath = 'output.txt',
    # Columns to be removed, any order, dupes are allowed
    [int[]] $Remove = (1, 2, 2),
    # Column separator
    [string] $Separator = '|',
    # Input file encoding
    [Text.Encoding] $Encoding = [Text.Encoding]::Default
)

$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'

# Gets rid of dupes and provides fast lookup ability
$removeSet = [Collections.Generic.HashSet[int]] $Remove

$reader = $writer = $null

try {
    $reader = [IO.StreamReader]::new(( Convert-Path -LiteralPath $InputPath ), $encoding )

    $null = New-Item $OutputPath -ItemType File -Force  # as Convert-Path requires existing path

    while( $line = $reader.ReadLine() ) {

        if( -not $writer ) {
            # Construct writer only after first line has been read, so $reader.CurrentEncoding is available 
            $writer = [IO.StreamWriter]::new(( Convert-Path -LiteralPath $OutputPath ), $false, $reader.CurrentEncoding )
        }

        $columns = $line.Split( $separator )
        $isAppend = $false

        for( $i = 0; $i -lt $columns.Length; $i++ ) {
            if( -not $removeSet.Contains( $i ) ) {
                if( $isAppend ) { $writer.Write( $separator ) }
                $writer.Write( $columns[ $i ] )
                $isAppend = $true
            }
        }

        $writer.WriteLine()  # Write (CR)LF
    }
}
finally {
    # Make sure to dispose the reader and writer so files get closed.
    if( $writer ) { $writer.Dispose() }
    if( $reader ) { $reader.Dispose() }
}
```

- `Convert-Path` is used because .NET has a different *current directory* than PowerShell, so it's best practice to pass absolute paths to .NET API.
- If this still isn't fast enough, consider writing this in C# instead. Especially with such "low level" code, C# tends to be faster. You may embed C# code in PowerShell using `Add-Type -TypeDefinition $csCode`.
- As another optimization, instead of using `String.Split()` which creates more sub strings than actually needed, you may use `String.IndexOf()` and `String.Substring()` to only extract the necessary columns.
- Last not least, you may experiment with [`StreamReader`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamreader.-ctor?view=net-6.0#system-io-streamreader-ctor(system-string-system-text-encoding-system-boolean-system-int32)) and [`StreamWriter` constructors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamwriter.-ctor?view=net-6.0#system-io-streamwriter-ctor(system-string-system-boolean-system-text-encoding-system-int32)) that lets you allow to specify a buffer size.

Comment: zett42 thanks for above script and correction its really working very fast. in above scrip i am facing one issue. in my data one string is "Dear Team,…There is" and in new file created by above script its showing like "Dear Team,ï¿½There is"

Comment: @AdeelMushtaq Which encoding does the input file have? We may have to force it via `StreamReader` and `StreamWriter` constructor parameters.

Comment: @AdeelMushtaq I've added an `Encoding` parameter. You may try different values like `[Text.Encoding]::Default` to detect the encoding or `[Text.Encoding]::Unicode`. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encoding?view=net-6.0

Comment: @zett24 `[Text.Encoding]::Default` worked for me. again thanks for swift response and valuable input.

Answer (score 0):

Just a more native PowerShell solution/syntax:

```
Import-Csv .\Test.txt -Delimiter "|" -Header @(1..12) |
Select-Object -ExcludeProperty $Remove |
ConvertTo-Csv -Delimiter "|" -UseQuotes Never |
Select-Object -Skip 1 |
Set-Content -Path .\testoutput.txt
```

- For general performance hints, see: [PowerShell scripting performance considerations](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/scripting/dev-cross-plat/performance/script-authoring-considerations). Meaning that the answer from [**@zett42**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7571258/zett42) probably holds the fastest solution. But there are a few reasons you might want to defer from this solution if only for the note:

> ⚠ Note
>
> Many of the techniques described here are not idiomatic PowerShell and may reduce the readability of a PowerShell script. Script authors are advised to use idiomatic PowerShell unless performance dictates otherwise.

- (*Correctly*) using the [PowerShell Pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pipelines) might save a lot of memory (as every item will be immediately processed and released from memory at the end of the stream -when e.g. sent to disk-) where .Net solutions generally require to load everything into memory. Meaning, at the moment your PC runs out of physical memory and memory pages are swapped to disk, PowerShell might even outperform .Net solutions.

  - As the helpful comment "*note that calling Add-Content in every iteration is slow, because the file has to be opened and closed every time. Instead, add another pipeline segment with a single `Set-Content` call*" from [**@mklement0**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/45375/mklement0) implies: the `Set-Content` cmdlet should be at the end of the pipeline, after the (last) pipe (`|`) character.
- The syntax `... .{process{ ...` is probably an attempt to [Speeding Up the Pipeline](https://powershell.one/tricks/performance/pipeline). This might indeed improve the PowerShell performance but if you want to implement this properly, you probably don't want to [dot-source](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scripts?view=powershell-7.2#script-scope-and-dot-sourcing) this but invoke this via the [background operator `&`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators#background-operator-), See: [`#8911` Performance problem: (implicitly) dot-sourced code is slowed down by variable lookups](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/8911).
  Anyways, the bottleneck is likely the input/output device (disk), as long as PowerShell is able to keep up with this input/output device, there is probably no performance improvement in tweaking this.
- Besides the fact that the [later PowerShell versions (7.2)](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/scripting/install/installing-powershell-on-windows) generally perform better than Windows PowerShell (5.1), some cmdlets are improved. Like the newer [ConvertTo-Csv](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertto-csv) which has additional `-UseQuotes <QuoteKind>` and `-QuoteFields <String[]>` parameters. If you are stuck with Windows PowerShell, you might check this question: [Delete duplicate lines from text file based on column](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72613575/1701026)
- Although there is an easy way to read delimited files without headers using the `Import-Csv` cmdlet (with the `-header` parameter) using the `Import-Csv` cmdlet, there is no easier way to skip the `Cvs` header for the counter cmdlet `Export-Csv`. This can be worked around with the with: `ConvertTo-Csv |Select-Object -Skip 1 |Set-Content -Path .\output.txt`, see also: [`#17527` Add `-NoHeader` switch to `Export-Csv` and `ConvertTo-Csv`](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/17527)

Comment: my data is having spaces between pipes but above code is removing the spaces.
`Adeel|12|test|1234589|     |amount|00|123345678890|test|all|12|`